# Problem installed two different PHP on a Mac

Tags: php, xdebug, macos-big-sur

I have a strange problem with Mac OS. Problem mixing two versions.

When I look at the PHP version through the VSCode:

[image]

[image]

When I look at the PHP version through the terminal:

[image]

```
~ » php -v
PHP 8.1.0 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2021 02:36:02) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.1.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

When I run a page of code in XAMPP containing `phpinfo();`

[image]

```
PHP Version 8.0.6
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v4.0.6, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.1.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

I just want to have PHP installed on my system. What is the solution to my problem?

Comment: You have more than one PHP, e.g. a system one (installed with `brew` or any other way) and the actual from XAMPP (which Apache uses). Run `which php` to see where that executable is located. P.S. On Mac and Linux it's pretty common these days to have separate php.ini used by CLI and web server. Your output for 8.0.6 already confirms that: different config will be used as it has Xdebug while 8.1.0 does not have it.

Comment: Not a Mac user ... but anyway: you can alter your `PATH` env variable and prepend the path to PHP from XAMPP -- the system should look at that location first. If not: use symlink for your system wide one?

Comment: @LazyOne I know. But what is the solution? Mac can not change its path to XAMPP and XAMPP can not change its path to Mac! The browser executes the XAMPP path. But the terminal and VsCode follow the path of the Mac! As a result, the code works in the browser, but gives errors in VsCode and the debugger!

Comment: *"But what is the solution?"* I'm not Mac user so cannot give you exact command/instructions. But check these on how to change your `PATH` environment variable: https://www.google.com/search?q=change+path+on+mac . For example: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/